# How to make an observable from another observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable

```
  public get users(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.userData.asObservable();
  }
```

I want to create another  observable from this

```
  public get usedRoles(): Observable<Roles[]> {
    // create the observable to get all the roles from all users
  }
```

Where each `User` has an attribute `roles: Array<Role>`

I tried `flatMap` however getting stuck with the getting the right structure.

```
  public get usedRoles(): Observable<Role[]> {
    return this.users.flatMap(users => users.map(u => u.roles));
  }
```

But this is just giving me arrays of roles separately for each user as shown by this `this.usedRoles.subscribe(roles => console.log(roles));`

I want a single array with the distinct list of roles used by all users.

Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  public get usedRoles(): Observable<Role[]> {
    return this.users.flatMap((users) => {
      const roles = [];
      users.forEach((user) => {
        // roles = roles.concat(user.roles);
        user.roles.forEach(r => {
          if (!roles.some(role => role.id === r.id)) {
            roles.push(r);
          }
        });
      });
     return Observable.of(roles);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Fateh Mohamed for the soultion. I made a simple edit to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mapping a value into another value you can use the regular `map` operator.

`flatMap` should be when the result returned by your projection function is another observable.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

getUserRoles(): Observable<Role[]> {
  return this.users.pipe(
    map(users => users.reduce((roles, user) => [...roles, ...user.roles], [])),
    map(arr => [...new Set(arr)])
  )
}
```